# How to use current_user method in rake task rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task

I creating a rake task for sending SMS to user from an Organisation which is signed in as current_user and I have to send the organisation name in the end which is stored in the organisation table.
But the problem is that current_user method is not accessible in rake files.How can i solve this problem?

Comment: For async processing of tasks you might want to have a look at DelayedJobs http://blog.andolasoft.com/2013/04/4-simple-steps-to-implement-delayed-job-in-rails.html, rake tasks seem IMHO to be not the proper tool here

Comment: Rake commands have another environment, in your case seems like it doesn't relate to web(current_user is just a session)

Comment: @dsounded i have to find the cuurent_user organisation name, so what do you suggest i do instead

Comment: @jethroo does delayed job provide access to current_user method

Comment: You need to make a separate page(admin panel or something) for sending that sms, if you want current user - you need to perform that action with web user, otherwise do a rake but stub current_user with some 'AdminBot' default user if you need this

Comment: you can pass the current_user and all other needed params to the job (depends on how you design it) as soon as the job is picked up for execution it then can retrieve the needed user from the DB and do what it needs to do with it ;)

Comment: @jethroo thanks i am going for it, will let you know if i stumble into some difficulty

Comment: @dsounded i am not able to follow you can you write an answer for me giving some details

Comment: seems like guy above has answered your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution where i can create a background job for the required fields in another table and this solve my problem as i have user_id  in the table.

Answer (score 1):

firstly current user will not be available in rake task. It's just a session variable, rake tasks work as per schedule/time period.

If it is something like transaction sms then, it has to be real time and i don't see a need for rask task and hope you are aware of this.

When you want to send sms to all the users, something like welcome sms when they signup and with no time restrictions. In that case write the code to pull data from users based on timestamp and send sms to all that users. The clear process is, there has be a logic to pull data from database in your rake task to take care of it.

Update:
Keep a track of users for whom sms has to be sent, have a table something like bulkusers, save any related information which is required to be sent across in the sms. if you have user data saved, and organisation is associated to it. Just saving user info is fine, while rake task runs, pull across the organisation information.

To handle birthdays, write something User.where DOB is today's date. Schedule it using a background job to run every day at any specified time. This should server the purpose

Comment: actually i want the message signed by the Organisation name that is currently signed in, thats why i need the current user method

Comment: also i forgot to mention the current_user method is not the devise method , i implemented my own signin signup without using devise

Comment: and the sms are on birthdays

Comment: I have query like this to fetch sms stored in User Setting table user_settings = UsersSetting.find_by(organisation_id: current_user.organisation_id, :facility_id => facility_id ,user_id: current_user.id)

Comment: You are wrong here, figure out the user. Have a flag to track the user else you will not be able to solve this